# smb drives can't write after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, samba

I have a home NAS accessed via smb share.

I used ubuntu 16.04 before and everythings fine. After I changed to 18.04, (not upgrading but erase-and-installing a new system, with the /home mounted at a different drive so not changed), It seems fine until I found all the folders in the NAS can only be read, any write operation will give an error.

I installed Xubuntu 18.04 first, when I tried to create a new folder in a NAS folder, the error message is :

> Fail to create directory "New Folder". 
>   Function not implemented. 
>   Do you want to skip it?

I tried Ubuntu 18.04 and get the same. And if I re-install the system with 16.04, the problem is gone.

I searched internet but couldn't find the answer. I found 16.04 and 18.04 have different cifs module versions, 16.04's cifs.ko is V2.08, while in 18.04 it's V2.10, is this the cause ? how to fix it?

p.s.:

If I mount the NAS folder by command line using:

```
sudo mount.cifs -o user=username,pass=mypwd //192.168.1.254/Documents /mnt
```

it can mount correctly, buy when I try to create a new file or folder in /mnt
, I got this error:

```
mn$ mkdir sjk
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘sjk’: Operation not supported
```

or

```
mnt>$ touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Operation not supported
```

Can anybody help with it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. At Ubuntu 17.10 I found I needed to add a `,vers=1.0` to my cifs/samba parameters, so I'd try that.  I primarily rely on NFS, using NFS devices only for backup so haven't paid much attention, but I have a number of parameters on mine you don't have "sec=ntlm,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777" but I'd suspect the version was what you are missing  (version bump made to avert WannaCry on windows clients)

Comment: Thanks vuiverc, I've tried to use the vers=xxx methods but seems not helping. As it will be back to normal if downgraded to 16.04, I reckon it would be a bug in 18.04?

Comment: I doubt a bug in 18.04, lots of people would have had it, and it would have been reported (*bugs aren't bugs until they have been reported [& confirmed] on launchpad.net for Ubuntu, and I can't find any*).  Did you try the sec=ntlm too?  I added the other lines in from my NAS lines so you could use them to try (as stated; I don't rely on samba but needed to add that on my `mount` some time back (*I forget which Ubuntu version but it was long ago*) for it to work for my devices.